# Changing the title of a custom WordPress integrated page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I need to add a custom page to a WordPress-based site, I always load the theme's header first:

```
<?php
  require('../wp-blog-header.php');
  include('../wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php');
?>
```

Unfortunately, then every custom page gets the same title (the blog's name) due to this code in *header.php*:

```
<head>
<title><?php if(is_home()) { bloginfo('name');} else { bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; the_title(); } ?></title>
```

What would be the best way to change this page title?

- Is there a WordPress method to call before loading the header that will change `the_title()`'s return value?
- Should I change the *header.php* call, so it will check if there is a previously defined custom value for my title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can look at your header code like this:

```
<?php
    if (is_home()) {
         bloginfo('name');
   } else {
         bloginfo('name'); echo ' | '; the_title();
    } ?>
```

Translating: if (it is your home) then print the blog's name. Else, print the blog's name, a | bar and the page/post title.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions,

1. Yes, there is; you might want to look at WordPress Hooks and Filters. A good list of available hooks and filters for WordPress 3.0 is [here](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/version/3.0).
2. I'd probably just use the `is_page()` WordPress function. You can use it as is to check whether WordPress is rendering a custom page, or supply a parameter (an id, a page title, etc.) to check for more specific ones.