# How can I change the title on a WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

Context: WordPress 5.4.5 and [Yoast SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoast_SEO) 3.7.1

I'm a plugin developer who has access to the client's site. The site has Yoast 3.7.1 installed. Is that significant, because no matter what I do I can't change the 404 page's `title`?

Now on other pages on Stack Overflow, where similar questions have been posed ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612840/struggling-to-set-page-titles-for-dynamic-php-pages-in-a-wordpress-site), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962548/wordpress-if-404-title) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570674/changing-the-title-of-a-custom-wordpress-integrated-page) for example), those answering have asked if the `header.php` is correctly embedding a call to `wp_title()`. Here's what's in the current theme's `header.php` at that point:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Interestingly, on my *404.php* page, `wp_get_document_title()` tells me that the document title is *Page not found - XXXX* even though the `wp_title` call above specifies the separator as `|`. Yoast's rewriting of titles has been disabled, so I'm not at all sure where that dash is coming from.

My plugin does a REST call and pulls in content from off-site for inclusion in the page. Part of that content is the text to be used in the `title`.

On previous client sites, I've been able to do the following:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'change_404_title');
function change_404_title($title) {
    if (is_404())
    {
        global $plugin_title;
        if (!empty($plugin_title))
        {
             $title = $plugin_title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

However, on this site, that's not working.

I have tried, based on the version of WordPress being used, hooking the `pre_get_document_title` filter, viz

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_404_title');
```

but again to no avail. I am currently reading up on Yoast...

Comment: Are you sure about this `global $plugin_title;` variable?

Comment: Totally. It's called something else but it's definitely there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`wp_title` has been deprecated since version 4.4. So we should use the new filter `pre_get_document_title`. Your code looks fine, but I am confused about `global $plugin_title`. I would rather ask you to *try* this first:

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_404_title');

function change_404_title($title) {
    if (is_404()) {
        return 'My Custom Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

If it doesn't work then try changing the priority to execute your function late.

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_404_title', 50);
```

Comment: I do like the look of the second suggestion. The priority might be the fix.

Comment: Yes, priority IS the fix. Thank you. Points and kudos to @KhorshedAlam

Answer (score 4):

How the document title is generated has changed since WordPress v4.4.0. Now `wp_get_document_title` dictates how the title is generated:

```php
/**
 * Displays title tag with content.
 *
 * @ignore
 * @since 4.1.0
 * @since 4.4.0 Improved title output replaced `wp_title()`.
 * @access private
 */
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
}
```

Here is the code from v5.4.2. These are the filters you can use to manipulate the title tag:

```php
function wp_get_document_title() {
    /**
    * Filters the document title before it is generated.
    *
    * Passing a non-empty value will short-circuit wp_get_document_title(),
    * returning that value instead.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $title The document title. Default empty string.
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'pre_get_document_title', '' );
    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        return $title;
    }
    // --- snipped ---
    /**
    * Filters the separator for the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param string $sep Document title separator. Default '-'.
    */
    $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '-' );

    /**
    * Filters the parts of the document title.
    *
    * @since 4.4.0
    *
    * @param array $title {
    *     The document title parts.
    *
    *     @type string $title   Title of the viewed page.
    *     @type string $page    Optional. Page number if paginated.
    *     @type string $tagline Optional. Site description when on home page.
    *     @type string $site    Optional. Site title when not on home page.
    * }
    */
    $title = apply_filters( 'document_title_parts', $title );
    // --- snipped ---
    return $title;
}
```

So here are two ways you can do it.

The first one uses the `pre_get_document_title` filter which short circuits the title generation and is hence more performant if you are not going make changes on the current title:

```php
function custom_document_title( $title ) {
    return 'Here is the new title';
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_document_title', 10 );
```

The second way uses the `document_title_separator` and `document_title_parts` hooks for the title and the title separator that are executed later in the function, after the title is generated using functions like `single_term_title` or `post_type_archive_title` depending on the page, and just before the title tags is about to be outputted:

```php
// Custom function should return a string
function custom_seperator( $sep ) {
   return '>';
}
add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'custom_seperator', 10 );

// Custom function should return an array
function custom_html_title( $title ) {
   return array(
     'title' => 'Custom Title',
     'site'  => 'Custom Site'
    );
}
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'custom_html_title', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php

```
function custom_wp_title($title) {

    if ( is_404() ) {
        $title = 'Custom 404 Title';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

10 - is priority change to overwrite other plugins like SEO

Comment: wp_title() was originally to be deprecated in 4.4, but was reinstated