# How to modify the < title > tag contents for some special wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress site with woocommerce. My products have not only categories, but also tags. For example, i have an url like:

https://example.com/product-tag/collection-1/

And it shows me all the products with tag "collection-1". In these pages in < title > tag there is something like "collection-1 - Site Name". I want to little change the format of text in < title >, like, for example, make it "Tag: collection-1 - Site Name". I read about wp_title() hook, but how to use the title change ONLY for these "product tag" pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this: [How can I change the title on a WordPress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415599/how-can-i-change-the-title-on-a-wordpress-page)

Basically that's the answer with a simple condition inside to check which page it is.

You can use is_single to check for specific pages : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

You can use is_archives https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/

is_category()
is_tag()
is_author()
is_date()
is_post_type_archive()
is_tax()

Use the one that makes sense here (which would be is_tag normally).

Comment: yes, so i can use is_tag() + wp_title(), thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to permalinks section in wordpress and edit it

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it in my case i do not want to change the permalinks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).